# in shell script how to print a line if the previous and the next line has a blank and the

Tags: shell

I have a file like

```
abc  
1234567890  
0987654321

cde

fgh

ijk  
1234567890  
0987654321
```

I need to write a script that extract the lines with a blank before and after, in the example should be like this:

cde
fgh

I guess that awk or sed could do the work but I wasn't able to make them work. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do share your tried code in your question, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
amt=$(sed -n '$=' path-to-your-file)
i=0
while :
do
  ((i++))
  if [ $i == $amt ]; then
    break
  fi
  if ! [ $i == 1 ]; then
    j=$(expr $i - 1)
    emp=$(sed $j'!d' path-to-your-file)
    if [ h$emp == h ]; then
      j=$(expr $i + 1)
      emp=$(sed $j'!d' path-to-your-file)
      if [ h$emp == h ]; then
        emp=$(sed $i'!d' path-to-your-file)
        echo >> extracted $emp
      fi
    fi
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
awk '
BEGIN{
    RS=""
    FS="\n"
    }
NF==1' file
```

Prints:

```
cde
fgh
```

Answer (score 0):

very simple solution

```
 cat "myfile.txt" | grep -A 1 '^$' | grep -B 1 '^$' | grep -v -e '^--$' | grep -v '^$'
```

assuming "--" is the default group separator

you may get ride of group separator by other means like
--group-separator="" or --no-group-separator options
but depends of grep program variant (BSD, Gnu, OSX... )